# Asset Pipeline Compile Only Javascript files

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, asset-pipeline

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile
```

which compiles assets and moves them into public/assets/ 
Now suppose i already compiled assets and deploy on production,
Now i comeback to my local machine and changes two lines in some javascript file
Now I have to run the task again while deploying on production.

I want that it should not compile css because i have not done any changes in css.
Is there any command which compiles only javascript

Like this

```
bundle exec rake assets:precompile --javascript
```

Comment: Bhai log koi tou answer de do

Answer (score 1):

Try this gem.
http://rubygems.org/gems/turbo-sprockets-rails3
It checks which file is changed and speed up precompile.